# How to simulate interaction with console programmatically?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to know how to programmatically execute commands (like "dir C:\" or "shutdown -r", etc.) in Windows' Command Prompt (CMD) and retrieve the resulted output, without displaying the black CMD window of course.

I suspect [->this link<-](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains the list of required APIs, but I'm not sure which ones to pick, so need your assistance.

Basically this is what I need it for: I want to write simple client-server application (WinSock) where user can sit on the client end and execute commands in (and read replies from) the command prompt of server. Yes - just like Telnet works, but without Telnet, just Win32 API.

Suppose user wants to execute "dir" command on server. He types "dir" on client application, which sends request to the server application, where the command will be executed (as if it was physically typed in command prompt of server) and the output text will be sent back to the client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this answer is not a good one for portable software, it works exactly the way you need it if you are sure everything is ok:

```
int system(const char *command);
```

This function executes `command` in shell (CMD in windows) if available.

By "if everything is ok" I mean you have a shell in your OS and it is available to you. Generally, this should be true for windows.

If you call it with `NULL`, it will give non-zero if shell is available. If you give an actual command, it either returns `-1` indicating an error (for example couldn't spawn a process), or return status of the command which should be OS dependent. Perhaps what you would be most concerned with is "if the command failed" and you should be good by checking the return value against 0 (0 being good).

Note that to get the output of the command, and you need to save the output somewhere. For example execute the `dir` command like this:

```
error = system("dir > temp.txt 2>&1");
```

and then retrieve its output from `temp.txt`.

Comment: Nope that won't help him. He wants the output too.

Comment: @MikeKwan, like I said, he can redirect the output to a file and then retrieve it.

Comment: @Shahbaz, I'm using 'system()' since ancient times but the inability of reading the output directly has always annoyed me. The redirection to file is not really the elegant solution, but if there is no better option, it's good to know anyway. But I'm still searching for the better solution.

Comment: @TX_, I believe the elegant solution is to basically implement every command using the windows API. Not to forget all the options that the user may give to those commands. Additionally, you need to be able to handle any kind of error, as well as making them optimized. A simple `copy` command copying a single file becomes 20 lines of code. For your platform specific task, `system` seems the best option to me.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically trying to reimplement one of the many possible uses of [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). By running on the windows system in a command prompt:

```
nc -l -L -e cmd -p 5555
```

and then running from another system

```
nc 192.168.1.xxx 5555
```

with `192.168.1.xxx` being the IP address of the windows machine you can do exactly what you are talking about: whatever you type will be "typed" on the windows machine and you will get the output from the remotely executed commands. You can also run netcat in an hidden window.

Note that because of this feature some antivirus blocks the netcat program... it has been apparently used by malicious software to transform PC of victims into slave bots.

Note also that routing input/output directly to `cmd` (the XP shell) is extremely dangerous as there is no authentication of any type: **anyone** can connect to port 5555 and execute commands on the machine, something you really don't want to allow unless you're in a very controlled environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Netcat is not part of Windows (though there are third-party ports for Windows) and even if it was, I need to do this programatically (it has to be the part of the larger client-server program). For manual testing netcat seems to be the wonderful tool, though.

Comment: @TX_ : Then grab the source code. There are OpenBSD and other Free implementations.

Comment: @MSalters, you can't just grab licensed code. If his program is not under a compatible license, that would be impossible.

Comment: @Shahbaz: That's why I wrote "OpenBSD and other Free" (as in FOSS)  implementations. The BSD license (as used in OpenBSD) is compatible.